# Risks about edit the source code of a Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am making my first steps coding. I made some courses on Internet, and now I started to make a Wordpress theme to continue learning from the practice.

I find that there is a lot of Plugins that can help me to achieve the goals that I want, and I also found a plugin that makes almost everything that I want.

I started to modify the source code of that plugin so it could fits in my design scheme. Now I don't know if it is a good idea.

I didn't find a way to make a "child plugin" so at this moment I don't know if continue editing the source of this plugin, (that means that I would never update my plugin because I would lose all the modifications) or simply make everything by my own that would take me a lot more of time.

Do you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look into world of hooks and filters.

[This](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) is nice place to learn from. [Here](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook) is list of WP hooks where you can hook your code.

And Woocommerce hook example how to cusom validate field.

First part: woocommerce_checkout_process is place where to hook code and my_custom_checkout_field_process is name of your function.

```
/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Some plugins have template files, that you can put into child theme.
But sadly not all plugins are well customizable.

Comment: This is amazing Margus, thank you very much! So it means that I can modify my pluggins using hooks, and can I add classes to it to can modify the css?

Comment: With hooks you can literally "hook" your code into some other code. But to overwrite whole plugin function I've first removed existing function like: 
remove_action('hook_connected_with', 'function_you_want_to_overwrite'); and then 
add_action('hook_connected_with', 'your_function'); 
function your_function(){/* Your code */}

hook_connected_with can be found in plugin files or wherever it is called out like:
do_action('hook_connected_with', 'function_you_want_to_overwrite'); If there's better way I'd like to hear about it too, but that's what I've been using. (hard to read code in comments..)

Comment: PS: Above code should go into child theme's functions.php file.